# How to conserve types in Kotlin enums?

Tags: class, enums, static, kotlin

I have an `enum` with 2 colors symbolizing an `on` and `off` pixel, one being a light gray and the other a much darker gray:

```
enum class Pixel(val state: Color) {
    ON (Color(200, 200, 200)),
    OFF(Color(50, 50, 50))
}
```

Now I have a custom `Image` object, that corresponds to an actual image on the disk and `img[x, y]`(ergo the `get`/`set` methods) either returns a `Color` object corresponding the the color of the pixel at position x,y in the image or accepts a `Color` object setting the pixel to that color. So `img[x, y] = Color(50, 50, 50)` works perfectly.

I would like to be able to do `image[x,y] = Pixel.ON/OFF` but `ON` and `OFF` are apparently of type `Pixel`.

How can achieve the effect I desire, being able to do `image[x,y] = Pixel.ON/OFF`? I have gotten it to work using `ON/OFF` as "static" members using a companion object but there must be a prettier and more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `Pixel` a singleton [`object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) that holds two properties of type `Color`, like so:

```
object Pixel {
    val ON = Color(200, 200, 200)
    val OFF = Color(50, 50, 50)
}
```

This gets you the desired syntax of `image[x, y] = Pixel.ON` and so on.

Comment: Thank you!! I almost resorted to doing a plain old Java class to get static properties.